# systemd can not start MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, systemd

I downloaded MongoDB from official site. Also I wrote systemd script to run it on ubuntu 15.10. Till today it was working just fine. But today, if I try to start MongoDB it works for ca. 30 seconds and then shuts down. In log file I see following:

```
"[signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends"
```

Here my systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description= MongoDB Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
PIDFile=/server/mongodb-server/mongod.pid
ExecStart=/server/mongodb-server/bin/mongod -f /server/mongodb-server/mongodb.conf


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried to delete "mongod.lock" but have same result.
Today, if I try to start Mongodb "sudo service mogodb start" it just hangs  for ca. 30 seconds and then responds with:

```
Job for mongodb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: This is definitely not a problem for software developers. But I am not sure if it should rather be posted on https://dba.stackexchange.com (because it's about administrating databases), https://unix.stackexchange.com (because it's about writing shell scripts) or https://serverfault.com (because it's about setting up actions on server restart)

Comment: See @Philipp comment. Does your data and log directory exists and does the `mongod` service have sufficient permissions to write and read to these locations.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was inconsistent file naming:
in "mongodb.service"

```
PIDFile=/server/mongodb-server/mongod.pid
```

and in "/server/mongodb-server/mongodb.conf"

```
pidFilePath: "/server/mongodb-server/mongodb.pid"
```

Comment: Please report this issue!

Comment: Version 2.6.11, doesn't like camel case for pitfilepath in mongodb.conf
Error parsing INI config file: unknown option pidFilePath

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar issue on a CentOS host.  The underlying cause was that mongo simply had a lot to do at startup, and took 4 min 47 sec to start.

The dirty hack workaround was to add

```
 TimeoutStartSec=400
```

to /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service and then `systemctl daemon-reload` and then a `start` was able to complete before the timeout.

The proper fix would be to optimise the data in mongo so it doesn't take almost 5 minutes to start.

Comment: Dirty but life saving :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I ran mongod as root while mongod was allready running under systemd.

When I did this the .lock and .turtle files under /var/lib/mongo no longer were oned by mongod and mongodb would not start under systemd only manually using "mongod -f -f /etc/mongod.conf"

The fix:

```
rm /var/lib/mongo/WiredTiger.lock /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock
chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo/*
```